# openvpn port is not bound correctly

Tags: openvpn

I have problem with running openvpn server

This is how it looks when I start it.

```bash
sudo openvpn server/server.conf
2023-10-25 13:30:22 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
2023-10-25 13:30:22 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-10-25 13:30:22 net_route_v4_best_gw query: dst 0.0.0.0
2023-10-25 13:30:22 net_route_v4_best_gw result: via 192.168.21.1 dev wlp11s0
2023-10-25 13:30:22 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
2023-10-25 13:30:22 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2023-10-25 13:30:22 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2023-10-25 13:30:22 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2023-10-25 13:30:22 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun0
2023-10-25 13:30:22 net_iface_up: set tun0 up
2023-10-25 13:30:22 net_addr_v4_add: 127.0.0.1/24 dev tun0
2023-10-25 13:30:22 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-10-25 13:30:22 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
2023-10-25 13:30:22 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
2023-10-25 13:30:22 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
2023-10-25 13:30:22 IFCONFIG POOL IPv4: base=127.0.0.2 size=253
2023-10-25 13:30:22 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
2023-10-25 13:30:22 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But `nmap` shows that port is not bound.

```bash
nmap 192.168.21.2 -p 1194
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-25 13:31 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.21.2
Host is up (0.00034s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1194/tcp closed openvpn
```

`lsof` also shows nothing

```bash
lsof -i -P -n | grep 1194
```

What can be the problem?